# VB.NET Make multiple subs with same name but different parameters

Tags: vb.net

I would like to make multiple subs with the same name but with different parameters.

For example:

```
Public Sub DoThis(Byval CustomerName As String)   
Public Sub DoThis(Byval CustomerID As Integer)
Public Sub DoThis(Byval CustomerID As Integer, ReferenceID As Integer)
```

But then VB.NET is telling me that such a sub already exists.
Can somebody please tell me how I can do this?

Thank you!

Comment: That should just work as long as the signatures are unique.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you’ve shown us absolutely works – VB won’t complain about this.

This is called *Overloading* and it’s an essential feature of .NET. However, in order for this to work you need to make sure that the signatures (i.e. the parameter type lists) are strictly *distinct* for all your overloads.

Here’s an example to showcase the importance of distinct parameter type lists:

```
Sub DoThis(CustomerName As String) …
Sub DoThis(ProductName As String) …
```

The subs look distinct. But how should VB handle the following call?

```
DoThis("Meyer")
```

It cannot know whether “Meyer” is a customer name or a product name (in fact, it could well be either!) – so VB forbids these declarations. However, the following is absolutely fine, because unambiguous:

```
Sub DoThis(Customer As Customer)
Sub DoThis(Product As Product)
```

```
DoThis(New Customer("Meyer"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Not sure what was going on in VB.NET and why it complained. I started a new project, and it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Been a while since I did VB .NET but I think you need to add the Overloads key word, so it will become:

```
Public Overloads Sub DoThis(Byval CustomerName As String)   
Public Overloads Sub DoThis(Byval CustomerID As Integer)
Public Overloads Sub DoThis(Byval CustomerID As Integer, ReferenceID As Integer)
```

Comment: You don’t *need* the `Overloads` keyword in this context. You *can* add it. It’s only required when distinguishing between an overload and override, though (and even then lack of `Overloads` will only issue a warning if I remember correctly).